# How does the mozilla stub installer works?

Tags: google-chrome, installation, mozilla, auto-update, silent-installer

I'm currently working on a no-touch deployment and auto-update mechanism for a Windows application. I've tried Microsoft ClickOnce strategy but it did not work for me as the strategy only suits small-sized apps, and my application hauls at ~500MB.

I'm interested in how the stub based installation and update strategies work for Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome and also Microsoft's packages including its .NET framework and VS installers. I've come across [Google Omaha](https://code.google.com/p/omaha/) which hosts the Google product update deployment mechanism, but it is not very conclusive for me.

Can anybody please help me out how the stub-based deployment design works?

**P.S.** Any open source code for the same would be of a great help. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite exactly sure of what you mean by "stub-based". There's a handful of technologies and tools involved in what I understand you want to accomplish. For the setup packages creation there are: [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and the [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/), for example. A core technology is [MSI](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=microsoft%20msi). On the other hand, for application updates and the such, there's [BITS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) and also some web stuff involved in updates publishing, like using an [ATOM feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29), for instance (your referenced *Google Omaha* might fit into this category).

It's only a bunch of pointers, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The Mozilla installer is opensource (as is the [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) system it uses) so I'd suggest adapting the code found here: http://lxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/toolkit/mozapps/installer/windows/nsis/

It's a bit complex so you could start with a simpler script and incorporate the bits you want (like finding/downloading updates and UAC evelation).

Comment: A better location is here: https://lxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/source/browser/installer/windows/nsis/stub.nsi